# What guns do the most damage in COD: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I noticed that certain guns are able to kill in fewer hits than others.  Some sniper rifles say they are "Deadly from the knee up".  What guns can kill in the least amount of shots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a rather handy web page that might help a little:

http://symthic.com/cod-ghosts-stats

Alternatively, play Hardcore where everything is lethal. :)

Answer (score 0):

A sniper rifle, if aimed correctly and hitting a key point on the body of the opponent will do more damage than say a pistol would in the same area.  I wouldn't worry about the actual bullet strength but rather what you are best with.  If you are a crack shot with a sniper rifle, that will be your best bet.  But if you can't aim to save your soul like me, then a weapon that burst fires (SMG, Assault, etc.) would be better to compensate for the aim issue.  But, if you truly want to know what weapon does the most damage, the sniper rifle is probably the most powerful - same with any explosive type weapons.

Answer (score 0):

The honey Badger is very deadly with burst fire and Tracker sight, or you can try any of the Sniper Rifles. Those are the best Weapons to pick.